# Stream cURL response to another cURL command posting the result

Tags: bash, curl, streaming

There's a public streaming Meetup API that streams JSON events: http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps

In a single line from the command line, I'd like to be able to redirect that stream such that each JSON object is POSTed to another API.

I've tried lots of permutations of cURL but thus far have been unable to make it work. My current attempt looks something like:

```
curl -s http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps | curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @- 'http://my-api-url-here'
```

This produces nothing as far as I can see. The requests are not streamed to the destination API and nothing is sent to standard out. As a bonus, I'd like to see the standard output but the core requirement is streaming the JSON records to the target API.

If I try redirecting the stream to a file like:

```
curl -s http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps > output.txt
```

This works as expected. The challenge seems to be getting the output from the initial cURL stream to POST as data to the second.

Comment: curl [does not support streaming data](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/290) at this time. You can split the stream into chunks and do multiple posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work for let's say, 10 events at a time

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "[$(curl -s http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps | sed -n '1{p; :loop n; p; 10q; b loop}' | sed -re '1,9 s/[}]$/},/')]" 'http://my-api-url-here'`

As suggested by [meetup docs](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/stream/2/rsvps/), the number of events may be limited using since_count and since_mtime.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I use it I get:

dquote cmdsubst quote>

It tried adding a closing ' to the sed expression but wasn't able to make it work.

Also, it looks like sed will collect 10 of the JSON objects. The API endpoint POSTing to only accepts valid JSON, meaning a single structure {} or an array of structures. It seems like if we use this approach, we'll need to add a comma between each structure and wrap the whole thing in an array []

Comment: Fixed the missing single quote and added more to build a list.