# Strange behavior Server Sent Events with WebFlux

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm new with Spring WebFlux. According to the other stackoverflow posts I'm trying to write a simple reactive endpoint, each second it should create and send a new book event. The problem is it only creates one book after that he stops producing objects although the stream channel is still up and running. 
This is my code:

Book.java

```
@Document(collection = "books")
public class Book extends SACDPObject{

  @NotBlank
  private String title;

  private Long test;


  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public Long getTest() {
    return test;
  }

  public void setTest(Long test) {
    this.test = test;
  }

}
```

NotificationController.java

```
@Slf4j
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/notification")
public class NotificationController {

 @CrossOrigin
  @GetMapping(path = "/books", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
  public Flux<Book> findBooks() {


    Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    Flux<Book> tFlux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(()-> new Book()));

    return Flux.zip(interval, tFlux).map(Tuple2::getT2);

  }
}
```

In order to test I use the cURL commands from my command line `curl -v http://localhost:8080/notification/books` but I can only see one book like this:

```
{
  "created" : "Sun Feb 24 13:57:06 CET 2019",
  "identifier" : "6f793ecc-9f67-4511-87f1-93c1f251e2eb",
  "title" : null,
  "test" : null
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your controller seems correct, looks like the problem in curl ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552653/stream-curl-response-to-another-curl-command-posting-the-result). You can check your endpoint for streaming in the Chrome browser.

Comment: Why is this a `@RepositoryRestController` and not a simple `@RestController`? What happens if you change that?

Comment: yes, that one was the issue. Yesterday I tried with @RestController and it worked. Thank you