# Redirect a cURL response to a cURL that POSTs, but not through a file

Tags: bash, curl, request, response, response.redirect

I 'd like to post directly a json object from a url(json) to another url

so the command goes as follows:

```
curl "<resource_link>.json" -o sample.json
curl -X POST "<my_link>" "Content-type: application/json" -d @sample.json
```

I 'd like to avoid this, so what is the solution? Is it something like that?

```
curl -X POST "<my_link>" "Content-type: application/json" -d "curl <resource_link>.json"
```

But it does not work? Also, this one post [Stream cURL response to another cURL command posting the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552653/stream-curl-response-to-another-curl-command-posting-the-result)
does not explain thouroughly and it is not working
Yes,

> curl

manual explains the '@' but it does not explain about using another curl
Alternatievely, if I could save somewhere temporarily the 1st cURL response and use it in the other command(but not in a file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You **don't** want `-x POST` in there so let's start with dropping that.
2. Send the results from the first transfer to stdout by *not* using `-o`, or telling `-o` to use stdout with `-o-`, and
3. Make sure your second transfer accepts the data to send on stdin, by using `-d@-`.

```
curl "<link>.json" | curl "<link2>" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d @-
```

### With curl 7.82.0 and later

Starting with curl 7.82.0 you can do it even easier with the new `--json` option:

```
curl "<link>.json" | curl "<link2>" --json @-
```